# Use GetResponse<T> with RoutingKey in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I looking for solution of following problem:
I have few TCP endpoints to which my GPRS devices are connecting.
I need to send TCP data to specific device which is connected to specific endpoint and receive response if it is sent or not.

So one device could be connected to one endpoint, another to other endpoint.
Each endpoint have configured Consumer which receive command and wite it to TCP stream.
My problem is that standard RequestClient -> Consumer architecture not specify which consumer receive message it use RoundRobin for dispatch messages to consumers.

Is there in box solution in MassTransit to specify RoutingKey in GetResponse method and during register Consumer?

My first idea was to register consumer with specific queue name, and create IRequestCLient with specific queue name according to selected Endpoint.

But maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the routing key when sending a request using the request client:

```cs
await client.GetResponse<SomeResponse>(new { SomeId = id }, 
    x => x.UseExecute(context => context.SetRoutingKey("device-123")));
```